# Is for loop or printf sequence preferred to create strings of n characters?

Tags: bash

What are the reasons to consider to choosing one method over the other?

`for sp in {1..1000}; do str=$str' '; done`

`printf -v str ' %0.s' {1..1000}`

Answer (score 2):

See the time difference on my system (macOS 10.15.6, bash 5.1 alpha):

```
$ time { str=; for sp in {1..1000}; do str=$str' '; done; }
real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time { str=; for sp in {1..1000}; do str=$str' '; done; }
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time { str=; for sp in {1..1000}; do str=$str' '; done; }
real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.014s
sys     0m0.000s
$
$ time { printf -v str ' %0.s' {1..1000}; }
real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time { printf -v str ' %0.s' {1..1000}; }
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time { printf -v str ' %0.s' {1..1000}; }
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
$
```

For this specific purpose, `printf -v str '%*s' 1000 ''` is even faster:

```
$ time { printf -v str '%*s' 1000 ''; }
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time { printf -v str '%*s' 1000 ''; }
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$
```

If the time performance does not matter for you, just pick anyone you like.